# Solving an unexpected interaction between ebgaramond and Franklin Gothic

Tags: fonts, fontspec

Here's my MWE, and its output (XeLaTeX, TeXLive 2012 latest, Windows 7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}     %%% <== This one
\setsansfont[%
    ]{ITC Franklin Gothic Std Book}
\newfontfamily\xffamily[%
    BoldFont=*,
    ]{ITC Franklin Gothic Std Book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\lipsum[39]
\xffamily
\lipsum[39]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The first paragraph is, unexpectedly, in bold type. (From the PDF, it's actually
Franklin Gothic Std Demi). If I eliminate the call to `ebgaramond`, everything comes out in normal type.

Although I know how to eliminate this (see the definition for `\xffamily`), I'd really like to know what's going on, as I really feel I *shouldn't need to.*

Can anyone enlighten me as to what's going on?

---

**Update 1**

`ebgaramond.sty` contains the following line:

```
\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{m}
```

If this line is removed, my problem goes away. However, I'd still like to understand what's happening here, especially as I don't think I'm invoking anything remotely bold.

---

**Update 2**

I'm in touch with Bob Tennent, the maintainer of `ebgaramond.sty`, who is examining the case...

Comment: I'd say that the choice made by the author of `ebgaramond.sty` is disputable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tried with Gill Sans, since I don't have ITC Franklin Gothic, but the result is the same. Here's what I get in the log file:

```
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
.
. Font family 'GillSans(0)' created for font 'Gill Sans' with options [,].
.
. This font family consists of the following shapes:
.
. * 'normal' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Gill Sans/AAT:"
.
. * 'normal' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Gill Sans/B/AAT:"
.
. * 'italic' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Gill Sans/I/AAT:"
.
. * 'italic' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Gill Sans/BI/AAT:"
.................................................
```

This refers to the "sans" family. Do you see where the thing goes wrong? Giving the meaning `m` to `\bfdefault` causes `fontspec` to assign the bold font to the medium weight *after* it has assigned the medium weight font.

Instead, for the definition of `\xffamily` I get

```
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
.
. Font family 'GillSans(1)' created for font 'Gill Sans' with options
. [,BoldFont=*, ].
.
. This font family consists of the following shapes:
.
. * 'normal' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Gill Sans/AAT:"
.
. * 'normal' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Gill Sans/AAT:"
.
. * 'italic' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Gill Sans/I/AAT:"
.
. * 'italic' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Gill Sans/I/AAT:"
.................................................
```

which is wrong either.

My conclusion is that `fontspec` relies on the meaning of `\mddefault`, `\bfdefault` and so on for assigning fonts to families and the setting made by `ebgaramond.sty` (in order to avoid messages about non-existing boldface font) is utterly wrong.

### "Solution"

```
\let\origbfdefault\bfdefault
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\let\bfdefault\origbfdefault
```